# unable to ping remote ipv6 with calico CNI for k8s

Tags: kubernetes, calico

Below is the manifest file i used to enable calico CNI for k8s, pods are able to communicate over ipv4 but i am unable to reach outside using ipv6, k8s version v1.14 and calico version v3.11,
am i missing some settings,

forwarding is enabled on host with "sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1"

```
   ---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-config.yaml
# This ConfigMap is used to configure a self-hosted Calico installation.
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: calico-config
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  # Typha is disabled.
  typha_service_name: "none"
  # Configure the backend to use.
  calico_backend: "vxlan"

  # Configure the MTU to use
  veth_mtu: "1440"

  # The CNI network configuration to install on each node.  The special
  # values in this config will be automatically populated.
  cni_network_config: |-
    {
      "name": "k8s-pod-network",
      "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
      "plugins": [
        {
          "type": "calico",
          "log_level": "info",
          "datastore_type": "kubernetes",
          "nodename": "__KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME__",
          "mtu": __CNI_MTU__,
          "ipam": {
              "type": "calico-ipam",
              "assign_ipv4": "true",
              "assign_ipv6": "true"
          },
          "container_settings": {
             "allow_ip_forwarding": true
          },
          "policy": {
              "type": "k8s"
          },
          "kubernetes": {
              "kubeconfig": "__KUBECONFIG_FILEPATH__"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "portmap",
          "snat": true,
          "capabilities": {"portMappings": true}
        }
      ]
    }

---
# Source: calico/templates/kdd-crds.yaml
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: felixconfigurations.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: FelixConfiguration
    plural: felixconfigurations
    singular: felixconfiguration
---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamblocks.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMBlock
    plural: ipamblocks
    singular: ipamblock

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: blockaffinities.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: BlockAffinity
    plural: blockaffinities
    singular: blockaffinity

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamhandles.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMHandle
    plural: ipamhandles
    singular: ipamhandle

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ipamconfigs.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPAMConfig
    plural: ipamconfigs
    singular: ipamconfig
---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: ippools.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: IPPool
    plural: ippools
    singular: ippool

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: hostendpoints.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: HostEndpoint
    plural: hostendpoints
    singular: hostendpoint

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: clusterinformations.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: ClusterInformation
    plural: clusterinformations
    singular: clusterinformation

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: globalnetworkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: GlobalNetworkPolicy
    plural: globalnetworkpolicies
    singular: globalnetworkpolicy

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: globalnetworksets.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Cluster
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: GlobalNetworkSet
    plural: globalnetworksets
    singular: globalnetworkset

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: networkpolicies.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: NetworkPolicy
    plural: networkpolicies
    singular: networkpolicy

---

apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: networksets.crd.projectcalico.org
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: crd.projectcalico.org
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: NetworkSet
    plural: networksets
    singular: networkset
---
# Source: calico/templates/rbac.yaml

# Include a clusterrole for the kube-controllers component,
# and bind it to the calico-kube-controllers serviceaccount.
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
rules:
  # Nodes are watched to monitor for deletions.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - watch
      - list
      - get
  # Pods are queried to check for existence.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
    verbs:
      - get
  # IPAM resources are manipulated when nodes are deleted.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ippools
    verbs:
      - list
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
      - ipamblocks
      - ipamhandles
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - update
      - delete
  # Needs access to update clusterinformations.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - clusterinformations
    verbs:
      - get
      - create
      - update
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: calico-kube-controllers
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
---
# Include a clusterrole for the calico-node DaemonSet,
# and bind it to the calico-node serviceaccount.
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
rules:
  # The CNI plugin needs to get pods, nodes, and namespaces.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
      - nodes
      - namespaces
    verbs:
      - get
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - endpoints
      - services
    verbs:
      # Used to discover service IPs for advertisement.
      - watch
      - list
      # Used to discover Typhas.
      - get
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes/status
    verbs:
      # Needed for clearing NodeNetworkUnavailable flag.
      - patch
      # Calico stores some configuration information in node annotations.
      - update
  # Watch for changes to Kubernetes NetworkPolicies.
  - apiGroups: ["networking.k8s.io"]
    resources:
      - networkpolicies
    verbs:
      - watch
      - list
  # Used by Calico for policy information.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods
      - namespaces
      - serviceaccounts
    verbs:
      - list
      - watch
  # The CNI plugin patches pods/status.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - pods/status
    verbs:
      - patch
  # Calico monitors various CRDs for config.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - globalfelixconfigs
      - felixconfigurations
      - ippools
      - ipamblocks
      - globalnetworkpolicies
      - globalnetworksets
      - networkpolicies
      - networksets
      - clusterinformations
      - hostendpoints
      - blockaffinities
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  # Calico must create and update some CRDs on startup.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ippools
      - felixconfigurations
      - clusterinformations
    verbs:
      - create
      - update
  # Calico stores some configuration information on the node.
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources:
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
 
  # These permissions are required for Calico CNI to perform IPAM allocations.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
      - ipamblocks
      - ipamhandles
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - create
      - update
      - delete
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - ipamconfigs
    verbs:
      - get
  # Block affinities must also be watchable by confd for route aggregation.
  - apiGroups: ["crd.projectcalico.org"]
    resources:
      - blockaffinities
    verbs:
      - watch
  # The Calico IPAM migration needs to get daemonsets. These permissions can be
  # removed if not upgrading from an installation using host-local IPAM.
  - apiGroups: ["apps"]
    resources:
      - daemonsets
    verbs:
      - get
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: calico-node
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: calico-node
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-node.yaml
# This manifest installs the calico-node container, as well
# as the CNI plugins and network config on
# each master and worker node in a Kubernetes cluster.
kind: DaemonSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-node
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-node
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-node
      annotations:
        # This, along with the CriticalAddonsOnly toleration below,
        # marks the pod as a critical add-on, ensuring it gets
        # priority scheduling and that its resources are reserved
        # if it ever gets evicted.
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      hostNetwork: true
      tolerations:
        # Make sure calico-node gets scheduled on all nodes.
        - effect: NoSchedule
          operator: Exists
        # Mark the pod as a critical add-on for rescheduling.
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
        - effect: NoExecute
          operator: Exists
      serviceAccountName: calico-node
      # Minimize downtime during a rolling upgrade or deletion; tell Kubernetes to do a "force
      # deletion": https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#termination-of-pods.
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      priorityClassName: system-node-critical
      initContainers:
        # This container performs upgrade from host-local IPAM to calico-ipam.
        # It can be deleted if this is a fresh installation, or if you have already
        # upgraded to use calico-ipam.
        - name: upgrade-ipam
          image: calico/cni:v3.11.3
          command: ["/opt/cni/bin/calico-ipam", "-upgrade"]
          env:
            - name: KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: calico_backend
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /var/lib/cni/networks
              name: host-local-net-dir
            - mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
              name: cni-bin-dir
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        # This container installs the CNI binaries
        # and CNI network config file on each node.
        - name: install-cni
          image: calico/cni:v3.11.3
          command: ["/install-cni.sh"]
          env:
            # Name of the CNI config file to create.
            - name: CNI_CONF_NAME
              value: "10-calico.conflist"
            # The CNI network config to install on each node.
            - name: CNI_NETWORK_CONFIG
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: cni_network_config
            # Set the hostname based on the k8s node name.
            - name: KUBERNETES_NODE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            # CNI MTU Config variable
            - name: CNI_MTU
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: veth_mtu
            # Prevents the container from sleeping forever.
            - name: SLEEP
              value: "false"
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /host/opt/cni/bin
              name: cni-bin-dir
            - mountPath: /host/etc/cni/net.d
              name: cni-net-dir
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
        # Adds a Flex Volume Driver that creates a per-pod Unix Domain Socket to allow Dikastes
        # to communicate with Felix over the Policy Sync API.
        - name: flexvol-driver
          image: calico/pod2daemon-flexvol:v3.11.3
          volumeMounts:
          - name: flexvol-driver-host
            mountPath: /host/driver
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
      containers:
        # Runs calico-node container on each Kubernetes node.  This
        # container programs network policy and routes on each
        # host.
        - name: calico-node
          image: calico/node:v3.11.3
          env:
            # Use Kubernetes API as the backing datastore.
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: "kubernetes"
            # Wait for the datastore.
            - name: WAIT_FOR_DATASTORE
              value: "true"
            # Set based on the k8s node name.
            - name: NODENAME
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: spec.nodeName
            # Choose the backend to use.
            - name: CALICO_NETWORKING_BACKEND
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: calico_backend
            # Cluster type to identify the deployment type
            - name: CLUSTER_TYPE
              value: "k8s"
            # Enable IPIP
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_VXLAN
              value: "Always"
            - name: CALICO_IPV6POOL_VXLAN
              value: "Always"
            # Set MTU for tunnel device used if ipip is enabled
            - name: FELIX_VXLAN
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: calico-config
                  key: veth_mtu
            # The default IPv4 pool to create on startup if none exists. Pod IPs will be
            # chosen from this range. Changing this value after installation will have
            # no effect. This should fall within `--cluster-cidr`.
            - name: CALICO_IPV4POOL_CIDR
              value: "192.168.128.1/18"
            - name: CALICO_IPV6POOL_CIDR
              value: "fd00::/80"

            # Disable file logging so `kubectl logs` works.
            - name: CALICO_DISABLE_FILE_LOGGING
              value: "true"
            # Set Felix endpoint to host default action to ACCEPT.
            - name: FELIX_DEFAULTENDPOINTTOHOSTACTION
              value: "ACCEPT"
            # Disable IPv6 on Kubernetes.
            - name: FELIX_IPV6SUPPORT
              value: "true"
            # Set Felix logging to "info"
            - name: FELIX_LOGSEVERITYSCREEN
              value: "info"
            - name: FELIX_HEALTHENABLED
              value: "true"
          securityContext:
            privileged: true
          resources:
            requests:
              cpu: 250m
          livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/calico-node
              - -felix-live
              #- -bird-live
            periodSeconds: 10
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            failureThreshold: 6
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /bin/calico-node
              - -felix-ready
              #- -bird-ready
            periodSeconds: 10
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /lib/modules
              name: lib-modules
              readOnly: true
            - mountPath: /run/xtables.lock
              name: xtables-lock
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /var/run/calico
              name: var-run-calico
              readOnly: false
            - mountPath: /var/lib/calico
              name: var-lib-calico
              readOnly: false
            - name: policysync
              mountPath: /var/run/nodeagent
      volumes:
        # Used by calico-node.
        - name: lib-modules
          hostPath:
            path: /lib/modules
        - name: var-run-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/run/calico
        - name: var-lib-calico
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/calico
        - name: xtables-lock
          hostPath:
            path: /run/xtables.lock
            type: FileOrCreate
        # Used to install CNI.
        - name: cni-bin-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /opt/cni/bin
        - name: cni-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /etc/cni/net.d
        # Mount in the directory for host-local IPAM allocations. This is
        # used when upgrading from host-local to calico-ipam, and can be removed
        # if not using the upgrade-ipam init container.
        - name: host-local-net-dir
          hostPath:
            path: /var/lib/cni/networks
        # Used to create per-pod Unix Domain Sockets
        - name: policysync
          hostPath:
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
            path: /var/run/nodeagent
        # Used to install Flex Volume Driver
        - name: flexvol-driver-host
          hostPath:
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
            path: /usr/libexec/kubernetes/kubelet-plugins/volume/exec/nodeagent~uds
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: calico-node
  namespace: kube-system

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-kube-controllers.yaml

# See https://github.com/projectcalico/kube-controllers
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
  labels:
    k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
spec:
  # The controllers can only have a single active instance.
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      name: calico-kube-controllers
      namespace: kube-system
      labels:
        k8s-app: calico-kube-controllers
      annotations:
        scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod: ''
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
      tolerations:
        # Mark the pod as a critical add-on for rescheduling.
        - key: CriticalAddonsOnly
          operator: Exists
        - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
          effect: NoSchedule
      serviceAccountName: calico-kube-controllers
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      containers:
        - name: calico-kube-controllers
          image: calico/kube-controllers:v3.11.3
          env:
            # Choose which controllers to run.
            - name: ENABLED_CONTROLLERS
              value: node
            - name: DATASTORE_TYPE
              value: kubernetes
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
              - /usr/bin/check-status
              - -r

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: calico-kube-controllers
  namespace: kube-system
---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-etcd-secrets.yaml

---
# Source: calico/templates/calico-typha.yaml

---
# Source: calico/templates/configure-canal.yaml
```

also i saw that all calico interfaces on host got same ipv6
fe80::ecee:eeff:feee:eeee/64
which is default ipv6 gateway for all pods

also observed when enabled vxlan it was not adding routes
vxlan.calico Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 66:6a:cb:79:4e:d7
inet addr:192.168.191.64  Bcast:192.168.191.64  Mask:255.255.255.255
inet6 addr: fe80::646a:cbff:fe79:4ed7/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1410  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:125 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.243.0.0      *               255.255.224.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.192.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.191.70  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali1c1c9f58b42
192.168.191.71  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali2fc31b4251c
192.168.191.72  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali5be518cf856
192.168.191.73  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali5e3a68f7b5f
192.168.191.74  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 cali59474b079db

Comment: what do you means "reach outside"? Can pods talk to each other under ipv6?

Comment: pods cant talk to each ovther over ipv6, i want containers to be able to communicate to external world , (example some other host on LAN with ipv6)

Comment: Kubernetes 1.15 and earlier only support one IP stack version at a time. You can not use ipv4 and ipv6 at the same time.

Comment: `ipip` and `vxlan` overlay network mode can not support ipv6 too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I communicated on slack channel of calico, and got info that i need to do config for dual stack for k8s and for calico

Comment: Will you add  details to your answer so that it is useful to others?

Answer (score 1):

We have faced the same issue we were able to reach through ipv4 and not working with ipv6.

We did the following,

```
# Reset the Cluster
kubeadm reset

# Create the cluster by adding the ipv6 CIDR along with the ipv4 address also enable IPv6DualStack 
# NOTE: The ipv6 given below matches the first 4 octet with Host ipv6 address ie., fde1
kubeadm init --kubernetes-version=v1.21.1 --apiserver-advertise-address=172.16.2.1 --feature-gates="IPv6DualStack=true" --pod-network-cidr=172.16.0.0/24,fde1::/64 --service-cidr=172.16.1.0/24,fde1::/112
```

By now we will have the ipv6 address seen for interfaces in all our PODs starting with "fde1:"

Even after configuring the above, we were not able to ping the external ipv6 address. Now we found that the packet reaches the target machine and comes back to the k8s host machine, but didn't reach the respective POD.

Now we found that we were missing some ip6tables rules. we enables the natOuting to true as below,

```
# cat /etc/calico/default-ipv6-ippool.yaml
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: IPPool
metadata:
  name: default-ipv6-ippool
spec:
  blockSize: 122
  cidr: fde1::/64
  ipipMode: Never
  nodeSelector: all()
  natOutgoing: true
  vxlanMode: Never
# calicoctl apply -f /etc/calico/default-ipv6-ippool.yaml
```

Now above created the entry in ip6tables and we can able to ping the external IPv6

Comment: Thanks for answer, but at present i don't have k8s setup to verify this, Also I just came across one more link https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/2954 where they mentioned to use environment var CALICO_IPV6POOL_NAT_OUTGOING=true instead of the config you have, May be it will be useful for you.When i tried it was k8s 1.14 which was not having support for dual stack.

Comment: Thanks Ragav, not sure where to apply this "CALICO_IPV6POOL_NAT_OUTGOING". we tried applying under calico-node in calico.yaml, its not working